# How to customize logging output for installation logfile?

Tags: java, install4j

Is it possible to change the output format for the installation logging like: `[date]|[time]|[content]?` Or maybe is it possible to include commons-loging or log4j to format the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 5.1.x, this is not possible. Adding automatic time stamps is planned for a future version.

You can register an installer event listener in a "Run script" action in the "Startup" node of the instaler to write the time stamps:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;

final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

context.addInstallerEventListener(new InstallerEventListener() {
    public void installerEvent(InstallerEvent event) {
        if (event.getType() == EventType.BEFORE_EXECUTE_ACTION) {
            Util.logInfo(event.getSource(), "Started action at " + 
                dateFormat.format(new Date()));
        } else if (event.getType() == EventType.AFTER_EXECUTE_ACTION) {
            Util.logInfo(event.getSource(), "Finished action at " + 
                dateFormat.format(new Date()));
        }
    }
});
```